# How to open colorbox after form submit that calls submit.php with location header?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, submit, colorbox

In order to prevent users from hitting their Back button after submitting a form, I want to open the next page in the colorbox modal. My form action is calling a php page which submits the data to MySql, then redirects to page.php using location header, where they are then asked to submit a photo as a secondary step in the submission process.

Here is the code I'm using on the first page with the submit buttonwhich opens the colorbox modal"

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".modal").colorbox({modal:true, width:"748px", height:"92%"});
  });
</script>

<form action='submit.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form1' onSubmit='jQuery.fn.colorbox()'>

// input data

<input name='save_button' type='submit' id='save_button' value='Save Settings'>
```

Here is the code for my submit.php page:

```
<?php
  // updatequery code
  header("Location: page.php");
?>
```

When clicking on the submit button, colorbox opens a modal, but then immediately closes while the code in submit.php page redirects to page.php

How do I get the form action=submit.php and the subsequent location header redirect page.php to come up in the colorbox modal?

Comment: Try submitting via ajax.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan I'm not having a problem submitting the data in the form upon submission. I'm having a problem opening the form action page inside the colorbox modal

Comment: I know that but the when the form is submit the whole content is get loaded again. So in that case you wouldn't be able to get any callback in which you can call colorbox code.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm a novice. I would need an example :)